# Windows forces update

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, shutdown

I have disabled updates on win 10 by going to run ->services.msc -> windwos updates.
Now the trick is, unless you hibernate, shutting down and restarting deletes this setting, and windows update runs the next time you turn on the laptop. How can the windows force shutdown? when battery is very low. I believe windows is exploiting this feature to force updates. it has happened multiply times. After it says battery low and shuts down, when I turn it on, battery is not low at all. What is going on here? Im very suspicious ... Wndows acts like battery is low, shuts down, turn on, updates run without you knowing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYk36.png)

Comment: You can’t disable Windows Update with any option within Windows Update, the best you can do, is constantly updating the Activity Hours every 12 hours.

Comment: If you are asking about how to stop windows forced updates, which i believe is what you're asking about then use [WUB](https://www.sordum.org/9470/windows-update-blocker-v1-7/)

Comment: thank you for suggesting WUB.
 I added a picture showing from where Im disabling it.

But my problem is what windows does to force update seems very hostile, and manipulative...

Comment: @Gaussianlover - Your method isn’t actually permanently disabling it. Your question is a duplicate of multiple existing questions.

Comment: I don't think your actual question has much to do with Windows Update. You need to focus on diagnosing and resolving the battery or shutdown issue, and afterwards you can deal with the Windows Update issue, except, you should really leave Windows Update enabled. There are very few valid reasons to actually disable Windows Update.